# Reorganizing dataset for List Length Analysis in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset with oppurtunistic species-observations per square kilometer per year (ranging from 1900 to 2019).

There are 139 different sites (square kilomters) in my dataset. I want to make a dataset where for each species for every year for every site, its presence or absence is stated with 1 or 0.

I think this is the appropriate format for including the length of the species-list per year per site in a GLM, to try and account for repeated visits to sites within years (See Szabo et al. 2010 sci-hub.tw/10.1890/09-0877.1 for application of this method).

Data now looks like:

```
Species     site      year
a           A         2001
b           A         2001
b           B         2001 
b           C         2002
c           B         2003
```

and i need it to be like:

```
Species      site     year   P/A
a            A        2001    1
a            B        2001    0
a            B        2003    0
a            C        2002    0

etc
```

I tried using various dplyer functions but i can't figure this one out. Its probably not that difficult, but i'm breaking my head over it for a few days now. Below I have 50 random samples from the dataset as a dput.

Dput of 50 random samples:

```
    structure(list(species = structure(c(476L, 355L, 76L, 210L, 470L, 
635L, 222L, 239L, 163L, 415L, 269L, 421L, 673L, 585L, 221L, 31L, 
184L, 386L, 88L, 197L, 30L, 678L, 355L, 136L, 471L, 152L, 303L, 
232L, 224L, 228L, 76L, 368L, 383L, 781L, 592L, 629L, 388L, 372L, 
191L, 172L, 340L, 366L, 604L, 730L, 350L, 593L, 426L, 251L, 495L, 
188L), .Label = c("Acer campestre", "Acer platanoides", "Acer pseudoplatanus", 
"Achillea millefolium", "Achillea ptarmica", "Aegopodium podagraria", 
"Aesculus hippocastanum", "Aethusa cynapium", "Agrostis canina", 
"Agrostis capillaris", "Agrostis gigantea", "Agrostis stolonifera", 
"Agrostis vinealis", "Aira caryophyllea", "Aira praecox", "Alisma lanceolatum", 
"Alisma plantago-aquatica", "Alliaria petiolata", "Allium vineale", 
"Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus incana", "Alopecurus aequalis", "Alopecurus bulbosus", 
"Alopecurus geniculatus", "Alopecurus myosuroides", "Alopecurus pratensis", 
"Alyssum alyssoides", "Amaranthus retroflexus", "Amelanchier lamarckii", 
"Ammophila arenaria", "Anacamptis morio", "Anagallis arvensis subsp. arvensis", 
"Anagallis tenella", "Anchusa arvensis", "Anchusa officinalis", 
"Anemone nemorosa", "Angelica archangelica", "Angelica sylvestris", 
"Anisantha sterilis", "Anisantha tectorum", "Antennaria dioica", 
"Anthemis arvensis", "Anthemis cotula", "Anthoxanthum odoratum", 
"Anthriscus caucalis", "Anthriscus sylvestris", "Anthyllis vulneraria", 
"Apera spica-venti", "Aphanes arvensis", "Aphanes australis", 
"Apium graveolens", "Apium inundatum", "Arabidopsis thaliana", 
"Arabis hirsuta subsp. hirsuta", "Arctium lappa", "Arctium minus", 
"Arctostaphylos uva-ursi", "Arenaria serpyllifolia", "Armeria maritima", 
"Armoracia rusticana", "Arrhenatherum elatius", "Artemisia campestris subsp. campestris", 
"Artemisia maritima", "Artemisia vulgaris", "Asparagus officinalis subsp. officinalis", 
"Asparagus officinalis subsp. prostratus", "Asplenium adiantum-nigrum", 
"Asplenium ruta-muraria", "Asplenium scolopendrium", "Asplenium trichomanes", 
"Aster tripolium", "Athyrium filix-femina", "Atriplex glabriuscula", 
"Atriplex laciniata", "Atriplex littoralis", "Atriplex patula", 
"Atriplex pedunculata", "Atriplex portulacoides", "Atriplex prostrata", 
"Avena fatua", "Azolla filiculoides", "Baldellia ranunculoides subsp. ranunculoides", 
"Ballota nigra subsp. meridionalis", "Barbarea vulgaris", "Bellis perennis", 
"Berula erecta", "Beta vulgaris subsp. maritima", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pubescens", "Bidens cernua", "Bidens connata", "Bidens frondosa", 
"Bidens tripartita", "Blechnum spicant", "Blysmus compressus", 
"Blysmus rufus", "Botrychium lunaria", "Brassica napus", "Brassica nigra", 
"Brassica rapa", "Bromopsis inermis subsp. inermis", "Bromus hordeaceus", 
"Bromus hordeaceus subsp. thominei", "Bromus racemosus", "Bromus secalinus", 
"Bryonia dioica", "Bupleurum tenuissimum", "Butomus umbellatus", 
"Cakile maritima", "Calamagrostis canescens", "Calamagrostis epigejos", 
"Callitriche brutia", "Callitriche obtusangula", "Callitriche platycarpa", 
"Callitriche stagnalis", "Calluna vulgaris", "Caltha palustris subsp. palustris", 
"Capsella bursa-pastoris", "Cardamine amara", "Cardamine flexuosa", 
"Cardamine hirsuta", "Cardamine impatiens", "Cardamine pratensis", 
"Carduus crispus", "Carduus nutans", "Carex acuta", "Carex acutiformis", 
"Carex arenaria", "Carex caryophyllea", "Carex diandra", "Carex distans", 
"Carex disticha", "Carex echinata", "Carex elata", "Carex extensa", 
"Carex flacca", "Carex hartmanii", "Carex hirta", "Carex nigra", 
"Carex oederi subsp. oederi", "Carex oederi subsp. oedocarpa", 
"Carex otrubae", "Carex ovalis", "Carex panicea", "Carex paniculata", 
"Carex pilulifera", "Carex pseudocyperus", "Carex pulicaris", 
"Carex riparia", "Carex rostrata", "Carex spicata", "Carex trinervis", 
"Carex vesicaria", "Carpinus betulus", "Carum carvi", "Castanea sativa", 
"Catabrosa aquatica", "Catapodium marinum", "Centaurea cyanus", 
"Centaurea jacea", "Centaurium erythraea", "Centaurium littorale", 
"Centaurium pulchellum", "Centunculus minimus", "Cerastium arvense", 
"Cerastium diffusum", "Cerastium fontanum subsp. holosteoides", 
"Cerastium fontanum subsp. vulgare", "Cerastium glomeratum", 
"Cerastium pumilum", "Cerastium pumilum/glutinosum", "Cerastium semidecandrum", 
"Ceratocapnos claviculata", "Ceratophyllum demersum", "Ceratophyllum submersum", 
"Chaenorhinum minus", "Chaerophyllum temulum", "Chamerion angustifolium", 
"Chelidonium majus", "Chenopodium album", "Chenopodium ficifolium", 
"Chenopodium glaucum", "Chenopodium murale", "Chenopodium polyspermum", 
"Chenopodium rubrum", "Cicendia filiformis", "Cichorium intybus", 
"Cirsium arvense", "Cirsium dissectum", "Cirsium palustre", "Cirsium vulgare", 
"Cladium mariscus", "Claytonia perfoliata", "Cochlearia danica", 
"Cochlearia officinalis subsp. anglica", "Cochlearia officinalis subsp. officinalis", 
"Comarum palustre", "Conium maculatum", "Convallaria majalis", 
"Convolvulus arvensis", "Convolvulus sepium", "Convolvulus soldanella", 
"Conyza canadensis", "Conyza sumatrensis", "Corispermum intermedium", 
"Corispermum marschallii", "Coronopus squamatus", "Corydalis solida", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corynephorus canescens", "Crambe maritima", 
"Crassula tillaea", "Crataegus monogyna", "Crepis biennis", "Crepis capillaris", 
"Crepis tectorum", "Crithmum maritimum", "Cuscuta epithymum", 
"Cymbalaria muralis", "Cynoglossum officinale", "Cynosurus cristatus", 
"Cytisus scoparius", "Dactylis glomerata", "Dactylorhiza incarnata", 
"Dactylorhiza maculata subsp. maculata", "Dactylorhiza majalis subsp. majalis", 
"Dactylorhiza majalis subsp. praetermissa", "Danthonia decumbens", 
"Datura stramonium", "Daucus carota", "Deschampsia cespitosa", 
"Deschampsia flexuosa", "Deschampsia setacea", "Descurainia sophia", 
"Digitalis purpurea", "Digitaria ischaemum", "Digitaria sanguinalis", 
"Diplotaxis muralis", "Diplotaxis tenuifolia", "Dipsacus fullonum", 
"Drosera intermedia", "Drosera rotundifolia", "Dryopteris carthusiana", 
"Dryopteris cristata", "Dryopteris dilatata", "Dryopteris filix-mas", 
"Echinochloa crus-galli", "Echium vulgare", "Eleocharis acicularis", 
"Eleocharis multicaulis", "Eleocharis palustris", "Eleocharis quinqueflora", 
"Eleocharis uniglumis", "Eleogiton fluitans", "Elodea canadensis", 
"Elodea nuttallii", "Elytrigia atherica", "Elytrigia juncea subsp. boreoatlantica", 
"Elytrigia maritima", "Elytrigia repens", "Empetrum nigrum", 
"Epilobium ciliatum", "Epilobium hirsutum", "Epilobium montanum", 
"Epilobium obscurum", "Epilobium palustre", "Epilobium parviflorum", 
"Epilobium roseum", "Epilobium tetragonum", "Epipactis helleborine subsp. helleborine", 
"Epipactis helleborine subsp. neerlandica", "Epipactis palustris", 
"Equisetum arvense", "Equisetum fluviatile", "Equisetum palustre", 
"Equisetum variegatum", "Eragrostis pilosa", "Erica cinerea", 
"Erica scoparia", "Erica tetralix", "Eriophorum angustifolium", 
"Erodium cicutarium", "Erodium lebelii", "Erophila verna", "Eryngium maritimum", 
"Erysimum cheiranthoides", "Euonymus europaeus", "Eupatorium cannabinum", 
"Euphorbia cyparissias", "Euphorbia helioscopia", "Euphorbia paralias", 
"Euphorbia peplus", "Euphrasia stricta", "Fagus sylvatica", "Fallopia convolvulus", 
"Fallopia dumetorum", "Fallopia japonica", "Festuca arenaria", 
"Festuca arundinacea", "Festuca filiformis", "Festuca gigantea", 
"Festuca pratensis", "Festuca rubra", "Ficaria verna subsp. verna", 
"Filago minima", "Filipendula ulmaria", "Fragaria vesca", "Fraxinus excelsior", 
"Fumaria officinalis", "Galanthus nivalis", "Galeopsis bifida", 
"Galeopsis tetrahit", "Galinsoga parviflora", "Galinsoga quadriradiata", 
"Galium aparine", "Galium mollugo", "Galium palustre", "Galium saxatile", 
"Galium uliginosum", "Galium verum", "Genista anglica", "Genista tinctoria", 
"Gentiana pneumonanthe", "Gentianella campestris", "Geranium dissectum", 
"Geranium molle", "Geranium purpureum", "Geranium pusillum", 
"Geranium robertianum", "Geum urbanum", "Glaucium flavum", "Glaux maritima", 
"Glechoma hederacea", "Glyceria declinata", "Glyceria fluitans", 
"Glyceria maxima", "Glyceria notata", "Gnaphalium luteoalbum", 
"Gnaphalium uliginosum", "Goodyera repens", "Gymnadenia conopsea", 
"Gymnocarpium dryopteris", "Hammarbya paludosa", "Hedera helix", 
"Heracleum mantegazzianum", "Heracleum sphondylium", "Herniaria glabra", 
"Hieracium aurantiacum", "Hieracium laevigatum", "Hieracium peleterianum", 
"Hieracium pilosella", "Hieracium umbellatum", "Hierochloe odorata", 
"Himantoglossum hircinum", "Hippophae rhamnoides", "Hippuris vulgaris", 
"Holcus lanatus", "Holcus mollis", "Honckenya peploides", "Hordeum marinum", 
"Hordeum murinum", "Hordeum secalinum", "Humulus lupulus", "Huperzia selago", 
"hyacinthoides non-scripta", "Hyacinthoides non-scripta", "Hydrocharis morsus-ranae", 
"Hydrocotyle vulgaris", "Hypericum perforatum", "Hypericum tetrapterum", 
"Hypochaeris glabra", "Hypochaeris radicata", "Ilex aquifolium", 
"Illecebrum verticillatum", "Impatiens parviflora", "Inula britannica", 
"Iris pseudacorus", "Isolepis setacea", "Jacobaea aquatica", 
"Jacobaea erucifolia", "jacobaea vulgaris", "Jacobaea vulgaris", 
"Jasione montana", "Juncus acutiflorus", "Juncus ambiguus", "Juncus articulatus", 
"Juncus balticus", "Juncus bufonius", "Juncus bulbosus", "Juncus capitatus", 
"Juncus compressus", "Juncus conglomeratus", "Juncus effusus", 
"Juncus gerardii", "Juncus inflexus", "Juncus maritimus", "Juncus pygmaeus", 
"Juncus squarrosus", "Juncus subnodulosus", "Juncus tenuis", 
"Juniperus communis", "Knautia arvensis", "Koeleria macrantha", 
"Lactuca serriola", "Lamium album", "Lamium amplexicaule", "Lamium hybridum", 
"Lamium purpureum", "Lapsana communis", "Lathyrus japonicus", 
"Lathyrus palustris", "Lathyrus pratensis", "Lathyrus tuberosus", 
"Leersia oryzoides", "Lemna gibba", "Lemna minor", "Lemna minuta", 
"Lemna trisulca", "Lemna turionifera", "Leontodon autumnalis", 
"Leontodon saxatilis", "Leonurus cardiaca", "Lepidium draba", 
"Lepidium ruderale", "Leucanthemum vulgare", "Leymus arenarius", 
"Ligustrum vulgare", "Limonium vulgare", "Limosella aquatica", 
"Linaria vulgaris", "Linnaea borealis", "Linum catharticum", 
"Liparis loeselii", "Lithospermum officinale", "Littorella uniflora", 
"Lolium multiflorum", "Lolium perenne", "Lonicera periclymenum", 
"Lonicera xylosteum", "Lotus corniculatus", "Lotus glaber", "Lotus pedunculatus", 
"Lupinus angustifolius", "Luronium natans", "Luzula campestris", 
"Luzula multiflora", "Lycium barbarum", "Lycopodiella inundata", 
"Lycopodium annotinum", "Lycopodium clavatum", "Lycopus europaeus", 
"Lysimachia nummularia", "Lysimachia thyrsiflora", "Lysimachia vulgaris", 
"Lythrum portula", "Lythrum salicaria", "Maianthemum bifolium", 
"Malus sylvestris", "Malva moschata", "Malva neglecta", "Malva sylvestris", 
"Marrubium vulgare", "Matricaria chamomilla", "Matricaria discoidea", 
"Medicago lupulina", "Medicago sativa", "Melilotus albus", "Melilotus altissimus", 
"Melilotus officinalis", "Mentha aquatica", "Mentha arvensis", 
"Menyanthes trifoliata", "Mespilus germanica", "Milium vernale", 
"Moehringia trinervia", "Molinia caerulea", "Moneses uniflora", 
"Monotropa hypopitys", "Montia minor", "Myosotis arvensis", "Myosotis discolor", 
"Myosotis laxa subsp. cespitosa", "Myosotis ramosissima", "Myosotis scorpioides subsp. scorpioides", 
"Myosotis sylvatica", "Myosoton aquaticum", "Myosurus minimus", 
"Myrica gale", "Myriophyllum alterniflorum", "Myriophyllum spicatum", 
"Myrrhis odorata", "Nardus stricta", "Nasturtium microphyllum", 
"Nasturtium officinale", "Neottia cordata", "Neottia ovata", 
"Odontites vernus subsp. serotinus", "Oenanthe aquatica", "Oenanthe fistulosa", 
"Oenanthe lachenalii", "Oenothera biennis", "Oenothera glazioviana", 
"Oenothera oakesiana", "Ononis repens subsp. repens", "Ononis repens subsp. spinosa", 
"Onopordum acanthium", "Ophioglossum vulgatum", "Ophrys apifera", 
"Oreopteris limbosperma", "Origanum vulgare", "Ornithogalum umbellatum", 
"Ornithopus perpusillus", "Orobanche caryophyllacea", "Osmunda regalis", 
"Oxalis corniculata", "Oxalis stricta", "Papaver argemone", "Papaver dubium", 
"Papaver rhoeas", "Parapholis strigosa", "Parnassia palustris", 
"Parthenocissus inserta", "Pastinaca sativa subsp. sativa", "Pedicularis palustris", 
"Pedicularis sylvatica", "Persicaria amphibia", "Persicaria hydropiper", 
"Persicaria lapathifolia", "Persicaria maculosa", "Persicaria minor", 
"Persicaria mitis", "Petasites hybridus", "Peucedanum palustre", 
"Phalaris arundinacea", "Phleum arenarium", "Phleum pratense subsp. pratense", 
"Phleum pratense subsp. serotinum", "Phragmites australis", "Picris echioides", 
"Picris hieracioides", "Pilularia globulifera", "Pimpinella saxifraga", 
"Pinguicula vulgaris", "Pinus sylvestris", "Plantago coronopus", 
"Plantago lanceolata", "Plantago major subsp. intermedia", "Plantago major subsp. major", 
"Plantago maritima", "Platanthera bifolia", "Poa angustifolia", 
"Poa annua", "Poa bulbosa", "Poa compressa", "Poa infirma", "Poa palustris", 
"Poa pratensis", "Poa trivialis", "Polygala vulgaris", "Polygonum aviculare", 
"Polygonum oxyspermum subsp. raii", "Polypodium vulgare", "Populus alba", 
"Populus nigra", "Populus tremula", "Portulaca oleracea", "Potamogeton berchtoldii", 
"Potamogeton crispus", "Potamogeton gramineus", "Potamogeton lucens", 
"Potamogeton mucronatus", "Potamogeton natans", "Potamogeton pectinatus", 
"Potamogeton polygonifolius", "Potamogeton pusillus", "Potamogeton trichoides", 
"Potentilla anglica", "Potentilla anserina", "Potentilla erecta", 
"Potentilla indica", "Potentilla reptans", "Prunella vulgaris", 
"Prunus avium", "Prunus padus", "Prunus serotina", "Prunus spinosa", 
"Pseudofumaria lutea", "Puccinellia distans subsp. borealis", 
"Puccinellia distans subsp. distans", "Puccinellia maritima", 
"Pulicaria dysenterica", "Pyrola minor", "Pyrola rotundifolia", 
"Pyrus communis", "Quercus petraea", "Quercus robur", "Quercus rubra", 
"Radiola linoides", "Ranunculus acris", "Ranunculus aquatilis", 
"Ranunculus baudotii", "Ranunculus bulbosus", "Ranunculus circinatus", 
"Ranunculus flammula", "Ranunculus lingua", "Ranunculus peltatus", 
"Ranunculus repens", "Ranunculus sardous", "Ranunculus sceleratus", 
"Raphanus raphanistrum subsp. landra", "Reseda lutea", "Reseda luteola", 
"Rhamnus cathartica", "Rhamnus frangula", "Rhinanthus angustifolius", 
"Rhinanthus minor", "Ribes nigrum", "Rorippa amphibia", "Rorippa palustris", 
"Rorippa sylvestris", "Rosa canina", "Rosa rubiginosa", "Rosa spinosissima", 
"Rubus caesius", "Rubus fruticosus", "Rumex acetosa", "Rumex acetosella", 
"Rumex conglomeratus", "Rumex crispus", "Rumex hydrolapathum", 
"Rumex maritimus", "Rumex obtusifolius", "Rumex palustris", "Ruppia cirrhosa", 
"Ruppia maritima", "Sagina apetala", "Sagina maritima", "Sagina nodosa", 
"Sagina procumbens", "Salicornia europaea", "Salicornia procumbens", 
"Salicornia pusilla", "Salix alba", "Salix aurita", "Salix caprea", 
"Salix cinerea subsp. cinerea", "Salix cinerea subsp. oleifolia", 
"Salix fragilis", "Salix pentandra", "Salix purpurea", "Salix repens", 
"Salix triandra", "Salix viminalis", "Salsola kali", "Sambucus nigra", 
"Sambucus racemosa", "Samolus valerandi", "Saponaria officinalis", 
"Saxifraga tridactylites", "Schoenoplectus lacustris", "Schoenoplectus pungens", 
"Schoenoplectus tabernaemontani", "Schoenus nigricans", "Scleranthus annuus subsp. annuus", 
"Scleranthus annuus subsp. polycarpos", "Scrophularia nodosa", 
"Scutellaria galericulata", "Sedum acre", "Sedum album", "Senecio inaequidens", 
"Senecio sylvaticus", "Senecio viscosus", "Senecio vulgaris", 
"Setaria pumila", "Setaria viridis", "Sherardia arvensis", "Silene conica", 
"Silene dioica", "Silene flos-cuculi", "Silene latifolia subsp. alba", 
"Sinapis arvensis", "Sisymbrium altissimum", "Sisymbrium officinale", 
"Sisymbrium orientale", "Sium latifolium", "Smyrnium olusatrum", 
"Solanum dulcamara", "Solanum nigrum subsp. nigrum", "Soliva sessilis", 
"Sonchus arvensis", "Sonchus arvensis ", "Sonchus asper", "Sonchus oleraceus", 
"Sonchus palustris", "Sorbus aucuparia", "Sparganium emersum", 
"Sparganium erectum", "Spartina anglica", "Spergula arvensis", 
"Spergula morisonii", "Spergularia media", "Spergularia rubra", 
"Spergularia salina", "Spirodela polyrhiza", "Stachys arvensis", 
"Stachys palustris", "Stachys sylvatica", "Stellaria graminea", 
"Stellaria media", "Stellaria pallida", "Stellaria palustris", 
"Stellaria uliginosa", "Suaeda maritima", "Symphytum officinale", 
"Tanacetum parthenium", "Tanacetum vulgare", "Taraxacum officinale", 
"Teesdalia nudicaulis", "Tephroseris palustris", "Teucrium scorodonia", 
"Thalictrum flavum", "Thalictrum minus", "Thelypteris palustris", 
"Thlaspi arvense", "Torilis japonica", "Torilis nodosa", "Tragopogon pratensis subsp. pratensis", 
"Trientalis europaea", "Trifolium arvense", "Trifolium campestre", 
"Trifolium dubium", "Trifolium fragiferum", "Trifolium hybridum", 
"Trifolium micranthum", "Trifolium ornithopodioides", "Trifolium pratense", 
"Trifolium repens", "Trifolium striatum", "Triglochin maritima", 
"Triglochin palustris", "Tripleurospermum maritimum", "Trisetum flavescens", 
"Tuberaria guttata", "Tussilago farfara", "Typha angustifolia", 
"Typha latifolia", "Ulex europaeus", "Ulmus glabra", "Ulmus laevis", 
"Ulmus minor", "Urtica dioica", "Urtica urens", "Utricularia australis", 
"Utricularia vulgaris", "Vaccinium macrocarpon", "Vaccinium myrtillus", 
"Vaccinium oxycoccos", "Vaccinium uliginosum", "Vaccinium vitis-idaea", 
"Valeriana officinalis", "Valerianella locusta", "Verbascum blattaria", 
"Verbascum densiflorum", "Verbascum nigrum", "Verbascum phlomoides", 
"Verbascum thapsus", "Veronica agrestis", "Veronica anagallis-aquatica", 
"Veronica arvensis", "Veronica catenata", "Veronica chamaedrys", 
"Veronica hederifolia", "Veronica officinalis", "Veronica peregrina", 
"Veronica persica", "Veronica scutellata", "Veronica serpyllifolia", 
"Viburnum opulus", "Vicia cracca", "Vicia hirsuta", "Vicia lathyroides", 
"Vicia sativa subsp. nigra", "Vicia sepium", "Vicia villosa", 
"Viola arvensis", "Viola canina", "Viola curtisii", "Viola odorata", 
"Viola palustris", "Viola riviniana", "Viola tricolor", "Vulpia bromoides", 
"Vulpia ciliata subsp. ambigua", "Vulpia fasciculata", "Vulpia myuros", 
"Zannichellia palustris", "Zannichellia palustris subsp. palustris", 
"Zannichellia palustris subsp. pedicellata", "Zostera marina", 
"Zostera noltei"), class = "factor"), site = c(142500599500, 
161500606500, 154500602500, 147500600500, 148500599500, 149500598500, 
150500601500, 148500598500, 158500604500, 153500601500, 147500599500, 
142500596500, 143500597500, 143500598500, 156500603500, 144500597500, 
142500598500, 142500599500, 156500602500, 152500601500, 148500600500, 
153500601500, 155500604500, 142500599500, 147500599500, 142500600500, 
160500604500, 150500601500, 149500601500, 140500599500, 146500599500, 
149500602500, 156500604500, 155500603500, 145500598500, 140500597500, 
152500601500, 148500599500, 155500603500, 145500598500, 144500599500, 
143500598500, 143500600500, 154500603500, 149500601500, 154500602500, 
141500597500, 144500598500, 151500601500, 162500604500), year = c(2016L, 
2011L, 1940L, 2015L, 2011L, 1901L, 2013L, 2011L, 1971L, 1901L, 
1996L, 2013L, 1989L, 2015L, 1984L, 2002L, 1993L, 2013L, 1993L, 
2002L, 2011L, 1948L, 1999L, 1945L, 1939L, 1999L, 2011L, 1995L, 
1900L, 1945L, 2011L, 1989L, 2012L, 1936L, 2016L, 2011L, 1993L, 
2014L, 1901L, 2016L, 1996L, 2014L, 1993L, 1937L, 1990L, 1901L, 
1993L, 2007L, 2015L, 1937L)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: In the dput output, what would be the 'site' column

Comment: So sorry! The dput is now correct, i merged the x and y coordinates and called it site now.

Comment: I updated the post.  May be that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, we can do a `complete` and create the binary

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(PA = 1) %>%
    group_by(species, site) %>%
    complete(year = unique(df1$year)) %>%
    mutate(PA =  replace_na(PA, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, the only thing is that it includes a lot of NA's in the new site row. Is it possible to name each row with the proper site?

Comment: @Stevestingray updated that part, now there is only 1 and 0

Comment: Thank you so much. This is perfect. I'll be sure to dive in the 'complete' function, since i don't know this one.